# How to implements pattern for below logic?

Tags: java, string

I tried with

```
public static void rightTriangle(int n) {
int rows, i, j=0;
String s = "Cheap flights from New York to United Kingdom";
String[] arr = s.split("\\s");
for (i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++) {
   for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        System.out.print(arr[j] + " ");
        System.out.println("");
   }
}
```

And I got

```
Cheap 
Cheap flights 
Cheap flights from 
Cheap flights from New 
Cheap flights from New York 
Cheap flights from New York to 
Cheap flights from New York to United 
Cheap flights from New York to United Kingdom
```

```
I 
I am
I am a
I am a girl

am
am a
am a girl

a
a girl

girl
```

Comment: Can you try to make a more readable question, I am not sure what you are asking

Comment: You have not included all your code and you have not told us what the problem is, or asked a question.

Comment: What is your expected output? What is each part of the code doing? What is in your for loop? Please provide a full [mre]

Comment: I re-edited kindly check it again please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you need to introduce one more for loop to get your desired output.

```
String s = "Cheap flights from New York to United Kingdom";
String[] arr = s.split("\\s");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = i; j < arr.Length; j++)
    {
        for (int k = i; k <= j; k++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[k] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    rightTriangle(3);
}
public static void rightTriangle(int n) {
    String s = "Cheap flights from New York to United Kingdom";
    String[] arr = s.split("\\s");
    for(int k = 0;k<arr.length-n;k++) {
        for (int i = k; i< arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = k; j <= i; j++)
                System.out.print(arr[j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

}
```

this should produce the correct output, you could tweak it to put it in a method yourself if needed however this should work fine. You can dictate how many triangles are displayed by changing the `rightTriangle(int n)` parameter, so if you put 0 in the method call it will draw all the triangles and if you put 8 it wont draw any because there are 8 words.

Comment: Okay thank you for your such encourage.

Comment: if you you put `n = arr.length-n;` somewhere in the `rightTriangle()` method, passing 8 as a parameter will result in displaying all 8 of the triangles while passing 0 in will display none of the triangles

Comment: Great, Im glad it worked, make sure if it worked for you that you mark the answer as answered, thanks!

Comment: Yes that part i got it.